# iPhone - using YouTube APIs in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I was going through the Google API for the iPhone but couldn't quite understand the use of YouTube API in iPhone apps. Neither could I find any good tutorials.

Can someone please point to documentation/samples which explain how to use the YouTube API in an iPhone app.

Thanks.

Comment: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Comment: Did see this. But it doesn't really tell how to do advanced operations with the API like searching through videos or channels.

Comment: how to display youtube playlist in the app?

Comment: @NandaKumar: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/

Answer (score 2):

Try out this link

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%@&start-index=21&max-results=20&v=2

replace the %@ with the text that you are searching it will return you xml parse it and get the data displayed in your controller

Hope this helps

Comment: if you open this link directly you will get a bad error, but dont worry replace the %@ with some text like ipad or ipod or what ever and then see