# Youtube API for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api

I was looking for some **YouTube API** implementation on iPhone but couldnt find and good resources.

I just want to know how to initialize the connection and call the function to display the list of youtube videos.

Can anyone help me out...

Any code will be very helpful...

Thanx in advance...

Comment: I found this page on YouTube which might point you in the right direction: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Comment: This might help you in building your application
[gdata-objectivec-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FYouTubeSample)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868113/iphone-using-youtube-apis-in-iphone-app